# How do I normalize a predesigned IIR filter?

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, normalization

Obviously  my question here is very similar to  this previously asked question: [How to normalize predesigned IIR filter coefficients to have unity gain?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24598/how-to-normalize-predesigned-iir-filter-coefficients-to-have-unity-gain)

Unfortunately, in the responses available to that question, it isn't super clear how the answers are obtained.
I have a pre-designed IIR filter that is applied in 2 steps:

Step 1:

```
    Yn =  Xn + a1*Yn-1 - b1*Yn-2
```

Step 2:

```
    Zn =  Yn + a2*Zn-1 - b2*Zn-2
```

with Xn being my initial input and Zn my final output.
Given these 2 pairs of coefficients (a1,b1) and (a2,b2), how do I go about finding the gain of this IIR filter to ensure it has unity gain.

Thanks for the help

Comment: DC gain or peak gain?  You could simulate it at http://www.micromodeler.com/dsp/.

Comment: Is his homework?  It sure looks like something I'd assign if I were teaching.

Comment: What makes sense here depends on the filter coefficients. These are second-order filters and they could have any characteristic (low pass, band pass, etc.). If they are low pass filters, then unity gain at DC makes sense, but not with band pass or high pass filters.

Comment: All, thanks for the comments. And no, this was not homework. This was backwards engineering of someone else's un-documented code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to choose a frequency $\omega_0$ at which you want to normalize the gain. This could be DC (i.e., $\omega_0=0$) or any other frequency, depending on the filter's characteristic.

You have two filters in series, each with transfer function

$$H_i(z)=\frac{1}{1-a_iz^{-1}+b_iz^{-2}},\qquad i=1,2\tag{1}$$

The total transfer function is just the product of the two individual transfer functions:

$$H(z)=H_1(z)\cdot H_2(z)\tag{2}$$

The gain at frequency $\omega_0$ equals the magnitude of the total transfer function $(2)$ evaluated at $z=e^{j\omega_0}$. So if you scale *one* of the two transfer functions $H_i(z)$ by the inverse of that gain, your total system will have unity gain at $\omega_0$.

Scaling in your time domain equations simply means scaling the *input* variable.

Note that $\omega_0$ is a normalized frequency in radians:

$$\omega_0=2\pi\frac{f_0}{f_s}\tag{3}$$

where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency.